# JavaScript -- Convert decimal to another base

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reinventing-the-wheel, converting, number-systems

The [Source code](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/decimal-to-base) is maintained on GitHub and may be cloned via the following commands. A [Live demo](https://javascript-utilities.github.io/decimal-to-base/index.html) is hosted online, thanks to GitHub Pages.

```bash
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/javascript-utilities
cd ~/git/hub/javascript-utilities
git clone git@github.com:javascript-utilities/decimal-to-base.git
```

The build target is ECMAScript version 6, and so far both manual tests and automated JestJS tests show that the `decimalToBase` function functions as intended, both for Browser and NodeJS environments.

I am aware of `(number).toString(radix)` for converting numbers to another base. However, the built-in `Number.toString()` method doesn't seem to have options for prefixing Binary, Octal, or Heximal bases; among other features that I'm implementing.

**Example Usage**

```
decimalToBase(540, 16);
//> "0x21C"
```

I am mostly concerned with improving the [JavaScript](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/decimal-to-base/blob/main/decimal-to-base.js), and [TypeScript](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/decimal-to-base/blob/main/ts/decimal-to-base.ts). The HTML and CSS are intended to be simple and functional.

Pleas post any suggestion to the JavaScript. Additionally if anyone has a clean way of handling floating point numbers that'd be super, because at this time the current implementation only handles integers.

```js
"use strict";
/**
 * Converts decimal to another base, eg. hex, octal, or binary
 * @function decimalToBase
 * @param {number|string} decimal
 * @param {number|string} radix - default `16`
 * @param {boolean} verbose - default `false`
 * @param {string[]} symbols_list - default `[...'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`
 * @returns {string}
 * @throws {SyntaxError|RangeError}
 * @author S0AndS0
 * @license AGPL-3.0
 * @see {link} - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal
 * @see {link} - https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals
 * @example
 * decimalToBase(540, 16);
 * //> "0x21C"
 */
const decimalToBase = (decimal, radix = 16, verbose = false, symbols_list = [...'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']) => {
    decimal = Math.floor(Number(decimal));
    radix = Number(radix);
    const max_base = symbols_list.length;
    if (isNaN(decimal)) {
        throw new SyntaxError('First argument is Not a Number');
    }
    else if (isNaN(radix)) {
        throw new SyntaxError('radix is Not a Number');
    }
    else if (radix > max_base) {
        throw new RangeError(`radix must be less than or equal to max base -> ${max_base}`);
    }
    else if (radix < 2) {
        throw new RangeError(`radix must be greater than 2`);
    }
    let prefix = '';
    switch (radix) {
        case 16: // Hexadecimal
            prefix = '0x';
            break;
        case 8: // Octal
            prefix = '0o';
            break;
        case 2: // Binary
            prefix = '0b';
            break;
    }
    if (radix >= 10 && decimal < 10) {
        return `${prefix}${symbols_list[decimal]}`;
    }
    let converted = '';
    let dividend = decimal;
    while (dividend > 0) {
        const remainder = dividend % radix;
        const quotient = (dividend - remainder) / radix;
        /* istanbul ignore next */
        if (verbose) {
            console.log(`dividend -> ${dividend}`, `remainder -> ${remainder}`, `quotient -> ${quotient}`);
        }
        converted = `${symbols_list[remainder]}${converted}`;
        dividend = quotient;
    }
    return `${prefix}${converted.toUpperCase()}`;
};
/* istanbul ignore next */
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = decimalToBase;
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.row::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 19%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

.text_input {
  float: right;
  width: 79%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tests Decimal to Base</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css"> -->

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modules/decimal-to-base/decimal-to-base.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function updateOutput(_event) {
        const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal').value;
        const radix = document.getElementById('radix').value;
        const output_element = document.getElementById('output');

        let output_value = 'NaN';
        try {
          output_value = decimalToBase(decimal, radix)
        } catch (e) {
          if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
            console.error(e);
          } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
            console.error(e);
          } else {
            throw e;
          }
        }

        output_element.value = output_value;
      }

      window.addEventListener('load', (_event) => {
        document.getElementById('decimal').addEventListener('input', updateOutput);
        document.getElementById('radix').addEventListener('input', updateOutput);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="label">Radix: </span>
        <input type="text" class="text_input" id="radix" value="16">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="row">
        <span class="label">Input: </span>
        <input type="text" class="text_input" id="decimal">
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="row">
        <span class="label">Output: </span>
        <input type="text" class="text_input" id="output" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

For completeness here are the [JestJS](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/decimal-to-base/blob/main/__tests__/tests-decimal-to-base.js) tests.

```javascript
"use strict";
/**
 * @author S0AndS0
 * @copyright AGPL-3.0
 * @example <caption>Jest Tests for decimalToBase</caption>
 * // Initialize new class instance and run tests
 * const test_decimalToBase = new decimalToBase_Test();
 * test_decimalToBase.runTests();
 */
class decimalToBase_Test {
    constructor() {
        this.decimalToBase = require('../decimal-to-base.js');
        this.decimal_limits = { min: 1, max: 16 };
        this.base_configs = [
            {
                base: 2,
                name: 'Binary'
            },
            {
                base: 3,
                name: 'Trinary'
            },
            {
                base: 4,
                name: 'Quaternary'
            },
            {
                base: 5,
                name: 'Quinary AKA Pental'
            },
            {
                base: 6,
                name: 'Senary AKA Heximal or Seximal'
            },
            {
                base: 7,
                name: 'Septenary'
            },
            {
                base: 8,
                name: 'Octal'
            },
            {
                base: 9,
                name: 'Nonary'
            },
            {
                base: 10,
                name: 'Decimal AKA Denary'
            },
            {
                base: 11,
                name: 'Undecimal'
            },
            {
                base: 12,
                name: 'Duodecimal AKA Dozenal or Uncial'
            },
            {
                base: 13,
                name: 'Tridecimal'
            },
            {
                base: 14,
                name: 'Tetradecimal'
            },
            {
                base: 15,
                name: 'Pentadecimal'
            },
            {
                base: 16,
                name: 'Hexadecimal'
            }
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Runs all tests for this module
     */
    runTests() {
        this.testsErrors();
        this.testsConversion();
    }

    /**
     * Uses `(Number).toString()` to check conversions, note this will only work for radix between `2` though `36`, and default `symbols_list`
     */
    static doubleChecker(decimal, radix) {
        decimal = Number(decimal);
        radix = Number(radix);
        let prefix = '';
        switch (radix) {
            case 2:
                prefix = '0b';
                break;
            case 8:
                prefix = '0o';
                break;
            case 16:
                prefix = '0x';
                break;
        }
        return `${prefix}${(decimal).toString(radix).toUpperCase()}`;
    }

    /**
     * Tests available error states
     */
    testsErrors() {
        test('Is a `SyntaxError` thrown, when `decimal` parameter is not a number?', () => {
            expect(() => {
                this.decimalToBase('spam!', 10);
            }).toThrow(SyntaxError);
        });
        test('Is a `SyntaxError` thrown, when `radix` parameter is not a number?', () => {
            expect(() => {
                this.decimalToBase(42, 'ham');
            }).toThrow(SyntaxError);
        });
        test('Is a `RangeError` thrown, when `symbols_list` is not long enough?', () => {
            expect(() => {
                this.decimalToBase(42, 37);
            }).toThrow(RangeError);
        });
        test('Is a `RangeError` thrown, when `radix` parameter is less than `2`?', () => {
            expect(() => {
                this.decimalToBase(42, 1);
            }).toThrow(RangeError);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Loops through `this.base_configs` and tests decimal integers between `this.decimal_limits['min']` and `this.decimal_limits['max']`
     */
    testsConversion() {
        const min = this.decimal_limits['min'];
        const max = this.decimal_limits['max'];
        this.base_configs.forEach((config) => {
            const { base } = config;
            const { name } = config;
            for (let decimal = min; decimal <= max; decimal++) {
                const expected_value = this.constructor.doubleChecker(decimal, base);
                test(`Base ${base}, does ${decimal} equal "${expected_value}" in ${name}?`, () => {
                    expect(this.decimalToBase(decimal, base)).toEqual(expected_value);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
const test_decimalToBase = new decimalToBase_Test();
test_decimalToBase.runTests();
```

---

### Questions

- Are there any mistakes?
- Have I missed any test cases?
- Any suggestions on expanding this implementation to handle floating point numbers?
- Any suggestions on making the code more readable?
- Are there any additional features that are wanted?

Comment: Deleting the radix 16 in the test code field generates an error and thereafter entering any radix number gives an error. Maybe it is the field entry code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @MohsenAlyafei. By design the `decimalToBase` function will throw a `SyntaxError` or `RangeError`, which _should_ be caught by in-lined JavaScript within the HTML. But for some reason CodeReview has their own _catcher_ which is adding an overlaid element, so it seems to be necessary to use the _"Expand snippit"_ so that errors do not hide elements used for input/output.

Comment: ``radix must be less than max base -> ${max_base}``.  If `max-base = 16` then this says "radix cannot be 16."

Comment: Not sure... do non-integer `decimal` parameter values get caught?

Comment: @radarbob Thanks for pointing out these bugs! I've corrected'em both on GitHub and here, as well as added ya to the list of attribution links.

Answer (score 2):

From the array variable:`symbols_list = [...'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`, I would assume that the function would permit the use of alternative symbols for representing numbers in formats above the decimal format. I have not come across such formats, like Hexadecimal numbers being represented by letters other than the English (Latin) letters A to F.

However, if you stick with the English letters A to Z, then I would suggest that you could simplify the process by using the built-in (number).toString(radix) (which you are already aware of) and then just add the needed prefix (which is only required for outputs in Binary, Octal, and Hex numbers).

I would do this by making use of the built-in function as follows:

```js
const decimalToBase = (decimal, radix = 16) => {
  let converted = (decimal).toString(radix);
  let prefix = '';
  switch (radix) {
    case 16:
      prefix = '0x';
      break;
    case 8:
      prefix = '0o';
      break;
    case 2:
      prefix = '0b';
  }
  return prefix + converted.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(decimalToBase(540));      // 0x21C  (default radix)
console.log(decimalToBase(123, 2));   // 0b1111011
console.log(decimalToBase(123, 8));   // 0o173
console.log(decimalToBase(123, 10));  // 123
console.log(decimalToBase(123, 32));  // 3R
console.log(decimalToBase(123, 36));  // 3F
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The `doubleChecker` method within the `decimalToBase_Test` class does mostly this, and the `symbols_list` parameter is there for those that want to experiment with bases larger than 36; which is the upper limit for `toString()` method on Numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I really like that you have JSDoc'ed the function, although I’d like to echo that it’s basically recreating `Number.prototype.toString`, down to the error types.

One thing I would like to address is the `[functional-programming]`-tag, because there seems to be a fair amount of misconceptions about the term.
In the case of prefixing the base, a functional approach might be along the lines

```
const compose = f => g => a => f(g(a))
const concat = a => b => String.prototype.concat.call(a, b)
const toBase = radix => n => Number.prototype.toString.call(n, radix)

const toBin = compose (concat ("0b")) (toBase(2))
const toOct = compose (concat ("0o")) (toBase(8))
const toHex = compose (concat ("0x")) (toBase(16))
```

utilizing the fact that functions can be both arguments to, and return values of functions. Which enables things like partial application and function composition, given curried (n-ary to unary) forms of the functions.

Regarding testing, you might consider using [property-based testing](https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-01-14-design-use-quickcheck.html) like [fast-check](https://github.com/dubzzz/fast-check) to generate random arguments that you might have not thought of.